# What does the Sm5Ge4 orthorhombic structure look like?

Tags: crystal-structure

I see tons of papers referencing this structure but none show what it looks like.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the $\text{Sm}_5 \text{Ge}_4$ crystal structure at Materials Project [here](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-1506/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In [Crystal structure of Sm5Ge4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X67000453), the structure is described as *orthorhombic* with $a = 7.75\,\mathring{A}$, $b = 14.94\,\mathring{A}$ and  $c = 7.84\,\mathring{A}$, having four $\ce{Sm5Ge4}$ units per unit cell. The authors further denote:

> The structure is conveniently described in terms of three layers which occur along the $b$ axis. Layer $G$ contains $\ce{Ge}$ atoms only; layer $S$ $\ce{Sm}$ atoms only Layer $C$ is a combination of $G$ and $S$, but with the roles of $\ce{Ge}$ and $\ce{Sm}$ interchanged. Layer $C$ serves as a mirror plane in $Pnma$, but only as a quasi-mirror plane in $Pn2_1a$. [...]

(*Personally, I find it a bit irritating that this article from 1967, which seemingly is the original reference, is not directly cited on the Materials Project page.)*